# Java exception error when using Scanner

Tags: java, error-handling

Can someone please help me see what the problem is. I realise that using 
    String kind = sc.next();
might bring a problem. if that's the issue how do i fix it. Thank you in advance. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Account {

protected static AccountNumber accountNumber; 
protected Customer customer = null; // not to be used yet

public abstract MeterNumber[] getMeterNumbers();
public abstract boolean exists(String meterNumber, String tariff);

public static Account load(Scanner sc) {
   while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
       AccountNumber accountNumber = AccountNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine());
       String kind = sc.next();
       sc.nextLine();
       if (kind.equals("D")) {
           return new DomesticAccount(sc, accountNumber);
       }   else {
               return new CommercialAccount(sc, accountNumber);
           }
      }    {
               return null;
           }
   }

}
```

The code in main is as follows.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Testt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Account.load(new Scanner("Accounts3.txt"));

        Map <AccountNumber, String> map1 = new HashMap <AccountNumber, String>();

        map1.put(Account.accountNumber, "hello");

        System.out.println(map1);

    }   
}
```

and this is the error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Account.load(Account.java:20)
    at Testt.main(Testt.java:14)
```

Comment: What if a mismatch input at `AccountNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine())`?

Comment: String kind = sc.next(); whats line 14?

Comment: whats line 14 in the main function?

Comment: Do you have enough lines in the "Accounts3.txt" file? Your `sc.hasNextLine()` while loop is followed by a `nextLine()`, then a `next()` and then another `nextLine()`; which is 3 items that it gets from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your are creating scanner on string object. Which is just "Accounts3.txt". Which is just one line.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)

I think you need to create scanner on file.

Refere this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)

So your main method will create scanner like this:

```
Account.load(new Scanner(new java.io.File("Accounts3.txt")));
```